# Connecting eye rig to head bone

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

I rigged the body of my character and proceeded to the facial rig, in which the eyes (mesh) are already connected to an armature, but now I want to connect those eyes armature to a new bone I made on his head so I can control both of them at the same time.

Adding to that, I also want to connect that new head bone to my master bone so I can move it all together.
Tried bone and object constraints, and parenting, but for some reason I can't seem to get it right. Everytime I move master bone (which you can't see on the image) in "Pose mode", the head bone and eye armature won't follow.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to adjust how you are trying to parent objects in order to solve the issue you are having.

When you want to parent an object to a bone that you plan to move with pose mode, you should try to parent it to the bone, rather than parent to the armature object.

[image: Parenting menu example]

Here is a simple workflow that should work for your situation.

1. Select the armature that you want to follow the bone in another armature
2. Now select the armature that contains the bone that you wish to parent to.
3. Use the parenting menu and select bone, or bone relative, depending on whether you want your child armature to retain its offset or not.

Hope that helps, happy blendering!

Note that:

If the armature containing the bone you want to parent to has multiple bones, you will need to select the proper one before doing so.

You can do that by going into pose mode prior to parenting, choose the bone that is to be the parent, then go back to object mode.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I'll try out that technique and get back to you only if it doesn't work :)